# Dynamic Select Choices in Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, cascadingdropdown

I want to creating a cascading Parent/Child selector, where the child options is based on the parent choice. The choices are from pre-defined variables/json. The user need to choose the parent option in order to get the respondent child options. So, by default the child has no option.

I implement the Ajax for populate the child choices in the admin form, however  when a model is saved, the child choices revert to initial state, which no options populated.

```
#choices
PARENT = {
    ('1','Parent 1'),
    ('2','Parent 2'),
    ('3', 'Parent 3'),
}
CHILD_CHOICES = {
    '1' : (("c1-opt1","Option 1-1"),("c1-opt2","Child option 1-2"),("c1-opt3","Child option 1-3")),
    '2' : (("c2-opt1","Option 2-1"),("c2-opt2","Child option 2-2"),("c2-opt3","Child option 2-3")),
    '3' : (("c3-opt1","Option 3-1"),("c2-opt3","Child option 3-2"),("c2-opt3","Child option 3-3"))
}
#model.py
class Relation(models.Model)
parent = models.CharField(max_length=4,choices=Parent,blank=True)
child = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I know I can customize the 'child' field in the admin.py, but I don't know to populate the options based on the saved model parent field in the page load.

```
#admin.py
class Cascadingform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Relation

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
    super(Cascadingform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if(self.parent): #not sure how to get the parent value here
        self.fields['child'] = forms.Select(choices=CHILD_CHOICES[self.parent])#  populated the choice based on the dict above.
```

The question is can I get the 'parent' value in the **init** so that I can use it to populate the child choices? Any idea?

Comment: Please, rename topic to swap "dynamic" with "cascading". You're getting **static cascading** choices at initialization time, not loading new **dynamic set of choices** (e.g. from another model, or queryset) when selecting parent option on the form in run-time. The topic name confuses.

Answer (score 1):

After days of googling, this is my solution:

```
def getFieldChoices(parent):
    CHILD_CHOICES = {
'1' : (("c1-opt1","Option 1-1"),("c1-opt2","Child option 1-2"),("c1-opt3","Child option 1-3")),
'2' : (("c2-opt1","Option 2-1"),("c2-opt2","Child option 2-2"),("c2-opt3","Child option 2-3")),
'3' : (("c3-opt1","Option 3-1"),("c2-opt3","Child option 3-2"),("c2-opt3","Child option 3-3"))}
    L = list()
    data = CHILD_CHOICES.get(parent, None)
    if data:
        L = [[x, x] for x in data]    
    return L


#admin.py
class Cascadingform(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cascadingform, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        if (self.instance.parent):
            self.fields['child'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'childclass'},choices=getFieldChoices(self.instance.parent))
                            )
        else:
            self.fields['child'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'childclass'},choices=[('','Select Parent First'),])
                            )
    class Meta:
        model = Relation
```